# Compute the sum $\sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^k \binom{n}{k}^3$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, proof-writing, binomial-coefficients

I have to calculate $\sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^k \binom{n}{k}^3$. I proved that for odd $n$ this sum equals to $0$ ($\binom{n}{k}$ and $\binom{n}{n-k}$ cancel each other out), but I have no idea how to approach an even $n$ case. Thanks!

Comment: I typed the sequence into [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A245086) and something called Chebyshev Polynomials popped up

Comment: The value is given by Dixon's identity (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dixon%27s_identity), a corollary of the MacMahon Master Theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacMahon_Master_theorem). The value for even integers is
$$\sum_{k=0}^{2n} (-1)^k\binom{2n}{k}^3=(-1)^n\frac{(3n)!}{(n!)^3}$$
I figure you may also be able to prove this result via induction.

Comment: Thanks, Jacob. That works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you already know about hypergoemetric functions
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^k \binom{n}{k}^3 x^k=\, _3F_2(-n,-n,-n;1,1;x)$$ Making $x=1$ and using Pochhamer symbols
$$\, _3F_2(-n,-n,-n;1,1;1)=\frac{(1-n)_n \left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right)_n}{(1)_n \left(1-\frac{n}{2}\right)_n}=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }\, 2^n\,\Gamma \left(\frac{3 n+2}{2}\right)}{\Gamma
   \left(\frac{1-n}{2}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)^2 \Gamma (n+1)}$$ which is zero if $n$ is odd. If $n=2m$
$$\frac{\sqrt{\pi }\ 4^m \,\Gamma (3 m+1)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{1-2m}{2}\right) \Gamma (m+1)^2 \Gamma (2m+1)}=(-1)^m\frac{(3m)!}{(m!)^3}$$ which is Dixon's identity